# problem fetching value from SELECT tag in my controller class in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

my view file - Index.cshtml 
---this is just a portion---

```
<form asp-controller="Getjob" asp-action="viewJob">

        <select name="category" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Choose Category</option>
            @foreach (var category in Model.ListB)
            {
                // loop through each product
                <option value="category.Name">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Name)</option>
            }


        </select>

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="FIND">

    </form>
```

my controller class 
---this method i am using---

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult viewJob(int cid)
        {
            using (var db = new JobportalContext())
            {
                jobs = db.Jobs.ToList();
            }

            foreach (Job item in jobs)
            {
                if (item.Cid == cid)
                {
                    jobsFiltered.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return View(jobsFiltered);
        }
```

my category class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace JobPortal.ProjModel
{
    public partial class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i am creating a filter method. so what i am trying to do is when i select a value from drop down list(select) and click on FIND button i want the form to pass a parameter which is -> id. but i cant figure out how to do that. It is an asp.net MVC project. this category class was created using EF core.

Help....

Comment: change <option value="category.Name">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Name)</option> to <option value="category.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Name)</option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the view ->

```
<form asp-controller="Getjob" asp-action="viewJob">
        <select name="category" class="form-control">
            <option value="0" selected disabled>Choose Category</option>
            @foreach (var category in Model.ListB)
            {
                // loop through each product
                <option value="@category.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Name)</option>
            }


        </select>

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="FIND">

    </form>
```

Controller code ->

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult viewJob(int cid)
        {
            cid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["category"]);

            using (var db = new JobportalContext())
            {
                jobs = db.Jobs.ToList();
            }

            foreach (Job item in jobs)
            {
                if (item.Cid == cid)
                {
                    jobsFiltered.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return View(jobsFiltered);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change view to

change the name property in select to *cid*

```
<form asp-controller="Getjob" asp-action="viewJob">
        <select name="cid" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Choose Category</option>
            @foreach (var category in Model.ListB)
            {
                // loop through each product
                <option value="category.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => category.Name)</option>
            }


        </select>

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="FIND">

    </form>
```

Comment: hey man its not working... i tried to debug it, turns out the value of 'id' is not reaching the controller class. it shows value of 0. how do i send this id value in form??

Comment: @mordor619 change the name property as well, then it should be fine